# Padrão zebrado no libreoffice

Tags: formatação-condicional, fórmula

No LibreOffice Calc, eu quero separar em uma lista de artistas e títulos, os artistas por meio de uma cor diferente.

Esse é o resultado que desejo:
[image]

Como podem ver, eu desejo que na coluna C uma fórmula indique se o artista da linha tem nos arredores artistas diferentes. Uma sequencia de artistas teria a mesma cor, enquanto três artistas alternados teriam cores alternadas. Por último eu faria uma formatação condicional com base nos resultados da coluna C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta:

```
=SE(A2=A1;D1;MOD(D1+1;2))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020/alternating-coloring-groups-of-rows-in-excel